# Liquibase <loadData> with file relative to the script file

Tags: liquibase

In liquibase, I can include file with path relative to the current script file:

```
<include file="initialise/data.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

In a change set, I can also point a file with the data I want to insert, e.g. like this:

```
<changeSet author="system-init" id="load-Company">
    <loadData tableName="Company" file="liquibase/initialise/Company.csv">
```

However, this time I need to use path relative to the current directory where I run the liquibase command. Is it possible to somehow use script-relative path here?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but it seems like a bad idea. Your changelogs, etc., should be stored in a revision control system in a consistent structure so that all users of the changelog have the same view of the world.

Answer (score 8):

This is solved in the latest version of Liquibase. See also:
https://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/liquibase-3-3-0-released.html

> Improvements
>
> [CORE-549] – relativeToChangelogFile for loadData, loadUpdateData,
>   sqlFile

Mind to update your XML schema location to the 3.3 version:

```
<xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd
               ">
```